# Calculate repeat purchase probability

Tags: python, pandas

I want to calculate repeat purchase probability based on the following example. I want to run this calculation on a Pandas DataFrame and I'm having a hard time figuring out how to do this incrementally for each row.

Example:

- Amount of customers who placed 1 order: 1,000
- Amount of customers who placed 2 orders: 350
- Amount of customers who place 3 orders: 130

In this example, the repeat order probability of customers who have placed one order in their lifetime to placing a second order is: (350 + 130) / (350+130+1,000) = 32.43%

Here's an example using iloc to get the same result as the example but it does not iterate through the dataframe.

```
lst = [[1, 1000], [2, 350],
       [3, 130], [4,70], [5,30]]
    
df = pd.DataFrame(lst, columns =['order', 'order_total'])
df['repeat_purchase_prob'] = df['order_total'].iloc[1:].sum() / df['frequency_total'].iloc[0:].sum()
```

And here's a link to the post I've read: https://blog.digitalj2.com/understand-the-power-of-repeat-order-probability

The end result should look like this:

| order | order_total | repeat_purchase_prob |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1000 | 0.37 |
| 2 | 350 | 0.40 |
| 3 | 130 | 0.43 |

And so on..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a reversed [`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html#pandas-series-cumsum) then [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html#pandas-series-shift) and divide:

```
rcs = df.loc[::-1, 'order_total'].cumsum()[::-1]
df['repeat_purchase_prob'] = rcs.shift(-1) / rcs
```

`df`:

```
   order  order_total  repeat_purchase_prob
0      1         1000              0.367089
1      2          350              0.396552
2      3          130              0.434783
3      4           70              0.300000
4      5           30                   NaN
```

---

Optional fill `NaN` with `0` via [`div`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.div.html#pandas-series-div):

```
df['repeat_purchase_prob'] = rcs.shift(-1).div(rcs, fill_value=0)
```

`df`:

```
   order  order_total  repeat_purchase_prob
0      1         1000              0.367089
1      2          350              0.396552
2      3          130              0.434783
3      4           70              0.300000
4      5           30              0.000000
```

---

Complete Working Example:

```
import pandas as pd

lst = [[1, 1000], [2, 350], [3, 130], [4, 70], [5, 30]]

df = pd.DataFrame(lst, columns=['order', 'order_total'])

rcs = df.loc[::-1, 'order_total'].cumsum()[::-1]
df['repeat_purchase_prob'] = rcs.shift(-1) / rcs

print(df)
```